# How do i calculate the difference between first and last event for each date per employee

Tags: sql, laravel

[How do i calculate the difference between first and last event for each date per employee][1]

```
Uid |     Checktime       | Utypename
 1    2020-01-08 16:59:33      In
 1    2020-01-08 17:07:28      In
 1    2020-01-08 17:07:31      In
 1    2020-01-08 18:01:46      In
 1    2020-01-09 17:07:28      In
 1    2020-01-09 16:59:33      In
 1    2020-01-09 17:07:28      In
 1    2020-01-09 17:07:31      In
 1    2020-01-09 18:01:46      In
```

To this

```
Uid     |       Ontime          |        Offtime           | Utypename
 1        2020-01-08 16:59:33      2020-01-08 18:01:46          In
 1        2020-01-09 16:59:33      2020-01-09 18:01:46          In
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `min()` and `max()`

```
select uid, min(Checktime) as Ontime,max(Checktime) as OffTime,Utypename
from tablename
group by uid, Utypename,date(Checktime)
```